# Store System.Windows.Controls into a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, controls

I need a dictionary that will have Type as key and Control as value. For example for Type of String, the Control will be TextBox; for Type of Boolean, the control will be radio button, and so on...
The problem is when I declare dictionary like `Dictionary<Type, Control>`, and try to add TextBox for example it says that TextBox is a type, which is not valid in a given context.
Any ideas?

Comment: Trying to do the same thing and not making much progress. Have tried using a dictionary with `key:[value, value value]` and an array format that for each one I could iterate through and then perform validation checks on each control but as yet no luck. I thought the easiest way would be to do separate keys for type and then control names under each type but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `Dictionary<Type, Type>` instead of `Dictionary<Type, Control>` since `TextBox` is `Type`:

```
private static Dictionary<Type, Type> s_ControlTypes = new Dictionary<Type, Type>() {
  {typeof(string), typeof(TextBox)},
  {typeof(bool), typeof(RadioButton)},
};
```

And then use it

```
// Let's create a control for, say, `bool` type:
Control ctrl = Activator.CreateInstance(s_ControlTypes[typeof(bool)]) as Control;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Dictionary<Type, Control> dictionary = new Dictionary<Type, Control>();
  dictionary.Add(typeof(string), textBox);
  dictionary.Add(typeof(bool), checkBox);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to add `Control` type (literally) to the dictionary, which should hold `Control` instances:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<Type, Control>();
dictionary.Add(typeof(string), TextBox);
```

You can't do this. You need either to put particular instance of `Control`, or, if this is just a some map for further reference, re-declare dictionary:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();
```

and fill it with *types*:

```
dictionary.Add(typeof(string), typeof(TextBox));
// and so on
```